# How does AWS evaluates IAM policies - under the hood?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

AWS policies have service-specific actions and conditions. Is the evaluation process(allow/deny) of these policies delegated to the respective services themselves or is this process centralized or a combination of both?

Answer (score -2):

The first result of a simple google search leads to the docs where they describe very well how it works. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html

Comment: Please explain, within your answer, how the content found at this link answers the specific question that has been asked.